# SQL server 2008 insert with select weird numeric behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having issues performing this insert:

```
INSERT INTO tblCoord (coordName, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT T1.NAME,
       T2.COL1,
       T2.COL2,
       T2.COL3
FROM table1 as T1
    INNER JOIN GD_DB.dbo.someview as T2
        ON T2.HOLEID = T1.NAME
```

Now, my problem is that col1,col2 and col3 from the tblCoord are numeric(28,16) and the col1,col2,col3 from t2 are floats.

When the inserts are made, 14959.95 becomes 14959.9500000000010000

How come, can this be fixed to keep 14959.9500000000000000?

*Im reading from an other database on the same instance

**Edit: Fixed doing `ROUND(CAST(T2.[colX] as numeric(28,16)),4)` to keep  a precision of 4

Comment: Don't mix data types...

Comment: Well, I can't decide datatypes , i'm transfering from an application database to another application database. I don't have control on them the programs are from other companies. My job is just to transfer datas and deal with that kind of problems :(

Comment: You have a problem, because floats do not store such values exactly whereas numerics do.  For instance, that is why monetary values should always be stored as `decimal` or `numeric`.

Comment: Does SQL Server support TRUNCATE? If it does, you can "clear" digits far right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow the question nor the accepted answer
The float is correct
Casting the flow back to to numeric is when you see the difference
Float is not exact and numeric is

```
declare @flt float = cast(14959.95 as numeric(28,16))
select  @flt                           -- 14959.95
select  cast(@flt as numeric(28,16))   -- 14959.9500000000030000
select  cast(@flt as numeric(28,2))    -- 14959.95
select  ROUND(cast(@flt2 as numeric(28,16)),4)   -- 14959.9500000000000000 fixes the output but does not really fix the data



declare @flt2 float = cast(14959.95 as numeric(28,2))
select  @flt2                          -- 14959.95 
select  cast(@flt2 as numeric(28,16))  -- 14959.9500000000010000
select  cast(@flt2 as numeric(28,2))   -- 14959.95
```

Comment: Woops, i misread the response but got inspired by it what I did was
ROUND(CAST(T2.[col1] as numeric(28,16)),4) 
gave me the good values with 0s to fill afterward

Answer (score 0):

As per Gordon Linoff's comment it is because floats are not exact values. Best way I can think to get around this is to cast as a numeric (28,2) first before storing as a numeric (28,16)

```
INSERT INTO tblCoord (coordName, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT T1.NAME,
       Cast(T2.COL1 as numeric(28,2)),
       Cast(T2.COL2 as numeric(28,2)),
       Cast(T2.COL3 as numeric(28,2))
FROM table1 as T1
    INNER JOIN GD_DB.dbo.someview as T2
        ON T2.HOLEID = T1.NAM
```